# Share iOS app .ipa file to client or tester without going through Apple TestFlight process

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, itunes, testflight

Share application .ipa file to the client or tester so you don't want to go through iOS Testflight process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**So, Here I'm sharing my answer for such questions** in two parts:
**[ IMPORTANT NOTE:

1. The client device or tester device UUID should be added in trusted device or device list on Apple appstore only then they will able to install the application.

2. Only 100 UUID you are able to add in a particular developer account.]**

1. Create .ipa file
2. Share .ipa file

**STEPS TO ACHIEVE OUR GOAL OF SHARING .IPA:**
***1. CREATE .IPA FILE***
Step 1: Select the iOS Device then Go to **Product Tab** --> **Compile** and **Build** Your Project Successfully.
 Step 2: Select the iOS device --> **Generic iOS Device** 
 Step 3: Go to the **Product** Tab and click on **Archive** to make an archive of your workspace or project. 
 Step 4: Once after achieve is successfully done, Go to the **Window** Tab --> Click **Organizer** 
 Step 5: Select your archive from the list of archives and click on **Distribute App**.
 Step 6: Select method of distribution as **ad Hoc** and click **Next** then select ad Hoc distribution option and select **App thinning** as NONE for all device and click **Next**
 Step 7: Select Signing Method as automatically signing or manual signing and click **Next**
Step 8: After successful compilation, you will see **Export** button and click **Export**
Step 9: Export the archive to desired location and after that Open the Export Folder you will see your .ipa file
 
*****2. SHARE .IPA FILE*****
 Step 10: Open [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) or [InstallOnAir](https://www.installonair.com/) and drag your .ipa file
 Step 11: After successfully uploading you will get the link or url for your .ipa
 Step 12: Share the link with client or tester, and say them to open it on safari browser to install the .ipa
**Hurray :) :) Its done and successfully installed.**
**Suggestion are always welcome

HAPPY CODING**